# Codename One code equivalent to Flutter Canvas.drawDRRect

Tags: codenameone

I have seen a Flutter component which I would like to transform to Codename One.

Flutter has a Canvas with has a method drawDRRect with "Draws a shape consisting of the difference between two rounded rectangles with the given [Paint]. Whether this shape is filled or stroked (or both) is controlled by [Paint.style]."

Any idea how I would do something similar in Codename One?

Comment: I guess there is no way to combine shapes, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `intersect` which lets you intersect two shapes. You can also use shape clipping but that has the drawback of being aliased so I'd keep this as the last resort.

You can `draw` or `fill` a shape. Draw will use the stroke style and a color. This isn't as versatile as other 2D API's that include a paint object but is performant.

You can also use mask images if the shape is static in which case you will have anti-aliasing.

Comment: I assume `intersect` is a method, right? A method of which class? I am unable to find it

Comment: Looking for it I found `com.codename1.ui.geom.GeneralPath.intersect(Shape)`which will throw an exception if the Shape is anything but a rectangle

Comment: intersect() requires one of the shapes to be a rectangle.  The other can be any shape.  Mostly this was created to support clipping functionality.